# Make video tag fit window vertically

Tags: css

I'm trying to limit the viewing area of a video element so that it doesn't flow past the bottom of the screen (it should be the same size as the dimmer layer that I have on top).

So if the viewport is 1440x600, the video should also be 1440x600. I added `overflow:hidden;` which afaik should do the trick.

CSS/HTML:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.dimmer {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.50;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <div class="dimmer"></div>
    <video autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="http://media.3daysawake.com/water-480p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sp76wL8x/4/

Comment: like this ? [LINK](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/NPMRgq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `vh` and `vw` attributes, which are based on viewport width and viewport height.

In this case, you only need the `vh`, I think.

If I understand correctly, the height of the video should be the screen height, and the width should adjust accordingly. So to do that, you can set the height to `100vh` (100% of viewport height).

You can play around with this, and set a width or max-width as well. The fun thing with this is that you can express the width of the video relatively to the height, for instance `min-width: 130vh` to make the width of the video at least 130% of the viewport height.

```
height: 100vh;
min-width: 130vh;
```